# How to make this as uppercase

Tags: mysql

Trying to make this encrypted text to become Uppercase using UPPER and UCASE but not working. Any possible way?

```
    set @thispass = 'thisismypassword';
    select Upper(pass) from
   (SELECT  concat_ws('','*',SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(@thispass)))) as pass)as rs
```

Comment: Can describe what `not working` means by way of example?

Comment: thanks @ Tim Biegeleisen, Make this result as Uppercase *c6d4d94530c4f559f4b42f0947e1164a359df6f

Comment: I get uppercase when I run your query, q.v. [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/82601).

Comment: Thanks i saw it but why is it not working in here? Is my Mysql Problem?

Comment: Maybe you have a collation thing going on or something.

Comment: I think so thanks @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: `SELECT upper(_latin1'string' COLLATE latin1_danish_ci);` ? ref http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-literal.html

Comment: Thanks @drew  but i tried to convert that way, its working.

Comment: make a self-answer if solved?

Comment: Yup, trying to find some possible way. But thanks then for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

select UPPER(Convert(pass using utf8)) from
(SELECT  UPPER(concat_ws('','*',SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1("thisismypassword"))))) as pass) as a